# If using a double weapon do you get multiple attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, double-weapons

If you don't have multiple attacks from your BAB but you have a double weapon like a quarterstaff, do you get multiple attacks if you take a full-round action or do you still need the bonus from the BAB for that to be valid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, a creature that wields a double weapon and that takes the full attack action can make 1 extra attack

Even if a creature lacks the feat [Two-weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat---final) *and* the creature's base attack bonus is less than +6, when wielding a double weapon and taking the full attack action the creature can make 1 additional attack. That's because according to the Combat Section on [Double Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting)...

> You can use a double weapon to make an extra attack with the off-hand end of the weapon as if you were fighting with two weapons. The penalties apply as if the off-hand end of the weapon was a light weapons. [*sic*]

*But* without the feat [Two-weapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat---final) or similar ability the standard penalties for [two-weapon fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting) apply: a −4 penalty on the attack roll with the first attack with either head of the double weapon, and a −8 penalty on the attack roll for the second attack with the *other* head of the double weapon.

So while a creature untrained in the art of two-weapon fighting *could* make that extra attack, it probably *shouldn't* unless circumstances are *really* stacked in its favor.

Comment: Anonymous User: Absent the feat Two-weapon Fighting, the penalty for fighting with two weapons (when the off-hand weapon's a light weapon) *or* for fighting with a double weapon (while using it as a double weapon) is, in fact and for-reals, −4 for the first attack and −8 for the second. However, if the wielder possesses the feat Two-weapon Fighting, the −4 and the −8 penalties are reduced to −2 each. Again, it says exactly that on the linked table. (Also, editing an answer to dispute it is really bad form.)